# Excel Visual Basic ComboBox-TextBox Linked With 2 Different Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I got 1 ComboBox-Linked with Cell (A195:1230)`[Purchasing_Group_List_CO]`  & 1 TextBox-Linked with Cell(B195:B230) `[PIC_Name]`. All I want is to change the value on ComboBox only and the TextBox will follow the rest. But I don't know which syntax do I need to shorten this code.

I'm totally new in this field, trying to understand VBA

Here's my code.

```
Private Sub Purchasing_Group_List_CO_Change()

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I10" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B195").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I20" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B196").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I21" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B197").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I22" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B198").Value)
    End If
     If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I30" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B199").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I31" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B200").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I32" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B201").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I40" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B202").Value)
    End If
     If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I41" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B203").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I42" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B204").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I50" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B205").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I51" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B206").Value)
    End If
     If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I52" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B207").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I60" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B208").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I61" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B209").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I62" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B210").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I63" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B211").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I71" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B212").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I72" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B213").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I73" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B1214").Value)
    End If
     If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I74" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B215").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I75" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B216").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I76" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B217").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I77" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B218").Value)
    End If
     If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I78" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B219").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I79" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B220").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I80" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B221").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I81" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B222").Value)
    End If

     If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I82" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B223").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I83" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B224").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I84" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B225").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I85" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B226").Value)
    End If

         If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I86" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B227").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I87" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B228").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I88" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B229").Value)
    End If

    If Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value = "I99" Then
        PIC_Name.Value = (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("B230").Value)
    End If




End Sub
```

All of those "I10,I20,I21...." is the value of cells (A195:1230).

Is there a way to shorten my line? I want it to be simple cause there will be another UserForm which based on thousands of different ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Private Sub Purchasing_Group_List_CO_Change()
    Dim v, m

    v = Purchasing_Group_List_CO.Value
    m = Application.VLookup(v, _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchasing Group Database").Range("A195:B230"), 2, False)

    PIC_Name.Value = IIf(IsError(m),"???",m)
End Sub
```

Comment: That works like a charm, @TimWilliams ! :) I really appreciate it, Many many thanks. Have a good day.